# Describing graduate certificate in written bio (US based)

Tags: united-states, cv

I have a graduate certificate from a US school (i.e. - Master's level work) and this program, in addition to offering graduate certificates, also offers graduate degrees.

Is it appropriate to describe myself in a written bio (rather than a resume, in which the certificate would be listed as given), as a 'graduate of the XYX school of economics'?

Answer (score 1):

**It depends.** There isn't always a lot of consistency to how graduate certificates holders are viewed. At some universities they are considered full alumni with all rights and privileges thereof. At other universities they you must hold a full degree (e.g., bachelors, masters, etc.) to be considered an alumni. In general, it is best to defer to the school's guidelines in terms of describing yourself as a graduate of the school or not.

However, it is always appropriate to list the certificate, i.e.,

> Graduate Certificate in Economics, *State University*, 20XX